# Getting value of a button label from a different ViewController

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsstring, uipopovercontroller

This seems to be quite trivial but somehow I can't get it to work. I have 2 Popover Controllers with a tableView as contents, and I have a UIViewController with some buttons. 
I'm setting one of the button's title from the PopoverController's didSelectRoxAtIndexPath function. This works nicely. Now I would like to pass this button title to the second PopoverController but can't seem to get this to work; the string returns a NULL. Currently I'm using:

h file:

```
NSString *myString;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *myString;
```

m file:

```
@synthesize myString;
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
MyAppViewController *appV = [[MyAppViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyAppViewController" bundle:nil];
self.myString = appV.buttonOne.currenTitle;
```

Comment: is the code above coming from the second view controller ?

Comment: Yes it is.Although now I put it into my main view controllers section where I load the second uipopover. Still not working tho. What seems to be strange is that the string value seems to be passed onto the popover, and the array I save the items I get from a plist file with this key are there, they are just not showing somehow.

Comment: why don't u try to use delegate variable ? I mean store a string in delegate variable and use it in diff views..

Comment: Sounds good but how do I exactly do this? :) Still a bit new to all this and even though this sounds trivial I would greatly appreciate a small code example if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting setting this property **before** displaying the second `UIPopoverController`.

Comment: Problem seems to be thats its not being retaind somehow. At least right before I display the UIPopoverController the value seems to be fine, gets set to NULL after it.